# javascript while loop, positive number given as a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I know that in javascript a *1* evaluates as *true*, while a *0* evaluates as *false*.

My question is regarding the **while** loop in javascript, in the format as follows:

```
while (condition) {
code block to be executed
}
```

If I pass a single integer as a condition for the while loop, how does the code function? More specifically, here is the code I was working on before posting this question:

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [];
  while (arr.length) {
    newArr.push(arr.splice(0,size));
  }
  return newArr;
 }

chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2);
```

and it seems to be working perfectly fine, returning the **newArr** the way I need it to by dividing the original array (**arr**) the amount of times required (**size**) and **push**ing that to the newArr.

How does the condition **arr.length** evaluate? My assumption is that it evaluates as true as long as it is not zero, i.e. a nonzero number, despite it not being a comparison such as i < 2.

This exercise came from freeCodeCamp:
*Chunky Monkey*

Comment: Your code is fine.  The `while` loop will execute until `arr.length` is zero.

Comment: Yes, any *non-zero* value is true in a conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Any number that is not `0` evaluates to `true`.
- `0` evaluates to `false`.

So, your code will run until `arr.length` is equal to `0` - it is the same as saying `while (arr.length!=0)`

Answer (score 0):

if you're evaluating array's length property, it will be true until array is not empty ( length is not 0 ). When the array is empty ( length is 0) evaluation will return false.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

Yes, you are absolutely right, it evaluates as true whilst `arr` has a length because `arr.length` is `> 0` so is considered true. It is a neat feature of `javascript` however it is not that readable (as you have found) and can therefore be confusing to anyone not used to it. However if you are coding for yourself, this is a clever little function!